# What is this plant with two kinds of leaves?

Tags: identification

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Height 180 cm or 6t, still growing. I thought it was another plant and therefore let it grow in spring, zone 7a in Europe. I did not notice another specimen, so I hope not invasive.

Could it be a Rudbeckia triloba? The thing is, it grew in a small area where I planted several rudbeckias from various sources. But this one is in many aspects different than tge rest of rudbeckias - it is larger, stems are of different color etc. Still did not flower.